# How do you use Apple Pay with CiviCRM?

Tags: civicontribute, payment-processor

I've seen Apple Pay on CiviCRM contribution pages before, but I don't know how to go about setting it up.  Does anyone know how it's done?

Comment: Do you recall where you saw this?

Comment: Many orgs whose Civi provider is OneEach Technologies has this, e.g.: https://www.svunitedway.com/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=11.  Some reading suggests it happens via Stripe, but I don't know how to configure it.

Comment: Here's the documentation from Stripe on how to implement their mobile payments button/system https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button

Answer (score 2):

You can use the stripe payment processor extension to handle stripe.

https://civicrm.org/extensions/stripe-payment-processor

But it only supports credit cards right now.  The maintainer is hoping to upgrade it to Stripe v3 which should support Apple Pay and lots of other wallets as well.

Comment: It looks like as of November 2019, ApplePay integration has been put off, for now: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/stripe/issues/81 "We made some good progress internally towards implementing this, but the refactoring for Stripe Elements and SCA has taken 2-3 times the expected amount of development and unfortunately we are not able to develop this under the Make It Happen funding. If additional funding becomes available we would be interested in developing this." from @mattwire